# Aplicação fechando (unfortunately MyApplication has stopped)

Tags: android

Estou fazendo a aplicação abaixo, do curso do Neri, porém quando implemento o código referente ao botão a aplicação fecha sozinha com erro

> unfortunately MyApplication has stopped

Se comentar o código do botão, a aplicação roda. Segue o código:

`MainActivity`

```
package br.com.calculadora;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText etNum1, etNum2, etResultado;
double num1, num2, resultado;
Button btSomar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    etNum1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.calculo_numero1);
    etNum2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.calculo_numero2);
    etResultado = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.calculo_resultado);

    btSomar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botao_soma);

    btSomar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(etNum1.getText().toString());
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(etNum2.getText().toString());     
            resultado = num1 + num2;
            etResultado.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));


        }

    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

`fragment_main`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="br.com.calculadora.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/titulo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/text1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/calculo_numero1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/calculo_numero1"
    android:text="@string/text2" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/calculo_numero2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/calculo_numero1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/botao_soma"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/resultado" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/calculo_resultado"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/calculo_numero2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/botao_soma"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/calculo_numero2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/calculo_numero2"
    android:text="@string/button1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

log do erro no `LogCat`:

```
03-18 16:18:54.339: D/AndroidRuntime(1879): Shutting down VM
03-18 16:18:54.339: W/dalvikvm(1879): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception    (group=0xb3a75ba8)
03-18 16:18:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(1879): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 16:18:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(1879): Process: br.com.calculadora, PID: 1879
03-18 16:18:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(1879): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start   activity ComponentInfo{br.com.calculadora/br.com.calculadora.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 16:18:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-18 16:18:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-18 16:18:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-18 16:18:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-18 16:18:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-18 16:18:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-18 16:18:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-18 16:18:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 16:18:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-18 16:18:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-18 16:18:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-18 16:18:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-18 16:18:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(1879): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 16:18:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at br.com.calculadora.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
03-18 16:18:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-18 16:18:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-18 16:18:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-18 16:18:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):     ... 11 more
03-18 16:23:54.839: I/Process(1879): Sending signal. PID: 1879 SIG: 9
```

Após as alterações sugeridas pelo @ExceptionAI, o código ficou:

`MainActivity`:

```
package br.com.calculadora;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    EditText etNum1, etNum2, etResultado;
    double num1, num2, resultado;
    Button btSomar;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        etNum1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.calculo_numero1);
        etNum2 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.calculo_numero2);
        etResultado = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.calculo_resultado);


        btSomar = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.botao_soma);

        btSomar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                num1 = Double.parseDouble(etNum1.getText().toString());
                num2 = Double.parseDouble(etNum2.getText().toString());     
                resultado = num1 + num2;
                etResultado.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));

            }

        });


        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

Segue tb o `activity_main.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="br.com.calculadora.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tive esse problema e resolvi assim:

```
/*
* A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
*/
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
```

Comment: Resolveu meu problema, muito obrigado @Euder

Answer (score 1):

Você está tentando locatilizar o botão no layout `activity_main` mas seu botão está no fragmento `fragment_main`, por isso ele é nulo.

Basta mover seu código do `onCreate` da activity para o `onCreateView` do fragmento e utilizar o rootView.

`btSomar = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.botao_soma);`

Comment: Não estou certo se o método `onCreateView()` é o local mais adequado para mover o código. Esse método não deveria exclusivamente retornar a view que compõe o fragment, de acordo com o ciclo de vida dos fragments?

Comment: @Piovezan Depende. O problema descrito é bem básico, o OP é obviamente iniciante em Android e então descrevi a forma mais simples de resolver o problema, sem entrar em detalhes da melhores prática do uso de fragmentos. Vamos um passo por vez.

Comment: @ExceptionAl, fiz como vc disse, mas o erro persiste, movi todo o código.

Comment: @JamesOrtiz Atualize a pergunta com o novo código e coloque também o xml do seu activity_main. Lembrando que era pra mover apenas o código do botão.

Comment: @ExceptionAl, coloquei o novo código, agradeço pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Pode ocorrer também quando é escrito uma caractere estranho ao código exemplo:
Implementação incorreta

```
.....
private String getClassName() {
        String s = getClass().getName();
        return s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(",")); 
    }
.....
```

Implementação correta

```
.....
private String getClassName() {
        String s = getClass().getName();
        return s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(".)); /*Observe que nesta linha    
                                        deve ter um ponto em vez da vírgula*/
    }
.....
```